# Ising Model in 1D with long range interaction

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, ising-model

I would like to arrive at the critical temperature for an Ising model with a long-range power-law Hamiltonian given by:
$$H = -\sum_{i=1}^{N}\sum_{j<i}\frac{J}{\lvert i - j\rvert^\alpha}\sigma_i \sigma_j.$$
How can we approximate the critical temperature using the mean field theory? I could get until what we do normally for $\alpha = 0$ case. That is,
$$\sigma_i \sigma_j = \langle \sigma \rangle \left(\sigma_i + \sigma_j \right) - \langle \sigma \rangle ^2,$$ where $\langle \sigma \rangle$ denotes the mean value of the spin.